# How to remove any data "http_proxy" module added or changed?

Tags: 7, feeds, http-request

I have a serious problem with a broken XML-Feed, that occurred after I installed http_proxy module. I have uninstalled the module, cleared the cache several times and even truncated the cache tables of the database manually. (I have to admit i didn't made a database backup before the installation). The XML feed is flawless, actually it didn't change at all.

I have following error messages:

in the drupal log:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in http_request_get() (Zeile 239 von
>   /example.com/sites/all/modules/feeds/libraries/http_request.inc).

The error message above is 2 times in the log with the same timestamp.
Then more recent:

> Warning: simplexml_import_dom(): Invalid Nodetype to import in
>   FeedsExXpathDomXpath->__construct() (Zeile 393 von
>   /example.com/sites/all/modules/feeds_ex/src/FeedsExXml.inc).

followed by
from the feeds module log:

> Start tag expected, '<' not found on line 1. Error code: 4

So i guess this comes from the http_proxy module. How can i remove any trace of it? Does someone have another idea where to look?

Thanks!

Comment: Somehow the headers could be malformed. There is a patch in https://www.drupal.org/node/2624918#comment-11301841. Can you tell there if it fixes your problem? For a better understanding of the problem it would also be useful if you can post the contents of the $header variable there. This is to verify if the proposed patch is correct.

Comment: I do see in the http_proxy issue queue that uninstalling the module does *not* uninstall the configuration. So the proxy configuration is likely still in place in your case: https://www.drupal.org/node/2592461

Comment: Oh, i have overlooked this issue. That would have led me to the right solution! Thanks a lot! Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling the HTTP proxy module appears to *not* uninstall its configuration. So the proxy configuration is likely still in place in your case. I assume that the reason the HTTP proxy module does not remove the configuration is that it doesn't explicitly "owns" the configuration: it exposes hidden settings from Drupal core.

There is an issue about this reported in the http_proxy issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2592461